# Declare the variable name repeatedly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am a beginner for IONIC. I use IONIC version 3.9

I found a problem on line 4 and line 11. File name "home.ts".

I guess that the problem is caused by the keyword "Homepage" but I don't know how to fix it. Please recommend me. Thank you.

```
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

export class HomePage {

    user_name: string = "";
    password_name: string = "";

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        private postPvdr: Postprovider,
        private appCtrl: App) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You said you found a problem on line 4 and line 14.
Which is the error at these lines what does it says ?

Comment: You're defining a type named HomePage, and alsa also importing a type named HomePage. Why don't you choose another name for your class?

Comment: @spritzig Typescript Error
Individual declarations in merged declaration 'HomePage' must be all exported or all local.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thank you. I'll try to fix.

Comment: @spritzig Typescript Error
Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'HomePage'.

Comment: @spritzig Typescript Error
Individual declarations in merged declaration 'HomePage' must be all exported or all local.

Comment: @wasanananta I am going to make a stackblitz with the same code and will check it.

Comment: @wasanananta What is `Postprovider` and why you are trying at contructor to call `App` ?
And as you have write `Error Import declaration` just delete the import `HomePage`